# Rails Angular webpack foreman

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, webpack

I created a new rails app with this command

```
rails new anrails --webpack=angular -d postgresql -T
```

and except few warnings and errors likes these

```
warning fsevents@1.1.2: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
warning "rails-erb-loader@5.0.2" has incorrect peer dependency "webpack@2".

An unexpected error occurred: "EPROTO: protocol error, symlink '../acorn/bin/acorn' -> '/vagrant/Sites/anrails/node_modules/acorn-dynamic-import/node_modules/.bin/acorn'".

warning "webpack-dev-middleware@1.11.0" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^1.0.0 || ^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0".
warning "webpack-dev-server@2.5.1" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^2.2.0 || ^3.0.0".

error An unexpected error occurred: "EPROTO: protocol error, symlink '../../../multicast-dns/cli.js' -> '/vagrant/Sites/anrails/node_modules/bonjour/node_modules/.bin/multicast-dns'".
```

I got the message: Webpacker successfully installed.

Then it installs the angular and its dependencies and get this error

```
error An unexpected error occurred: "EPROTO: protocol error, symlink '../../../json5/lib/cli.js' -> '/vagrant/Sites/anrails/node_modules/loader-utils/node_modules/.bin/json5'".
```

after this I get the message: Webpacker now supports angular and typescript.

So I create a Procfile in root folder of the app

```
web: bundle exec rails s -b 0.0.0.0
webpacker: bin/webpack-dev-server
```

and run foreman start and get the following

```
09:40:39 web.1       | started with pid 4514
09:40:39 webpacker.1 | started with pid 4515
09:40:40 webpacker.1 | yarn run v0.27.5
09:40:40 webpacker.1 | error Command "webpack-dev-server" not found.
09:40:40 webpacker.1 | info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
09:40:40 webpacker.1 | exited with code 1
09:40:40 system      | sending SIGTERM to all processes
09:40:41 web.1       | terminated by SIGTERM
```

Running in vagrant on Windows, ruby 2.4.1p111, Rails 5.1.2, node 6.11.1, yarn 0.27.5

Answer (score 0):

As your code is saying: `error Command "webpack-dev-server" not found.` there is something wrong in your bin folder.

Mine for example looks like this:
[image]

Check your folder first and see if everything is in place.

And.. Have you tried with the current folder dot?: `./bin/webpack-dev-server`?